# Why onReceive does not work in my BroadcastReceiver object? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I have `NotificationCenter` object for interaction with BroadcastReceiver

```
object NotificationCenter {

    fun addObserver(
        context: Context?,
        notification: NotificationName,
        responseHandler: BroadcastReceiver?
    ) {
        if (context != null && responseHandler != null) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                .registerReceiver(responseHandler, IntentFilter(notification.name))
        }
    }

    fun postNotification(
        context: Context?,
        notification: NotificationName,
        params: HashMap<String?, String?>
    ) {
        val intent = Intent(notification.name)
        for ((key, value) in params.entries) {
            intent.putExtra(key, value)
        }
        if (context != null) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent)
            Log.d("MyLog", "this log is printed")
        }
    }
}
```

Next I try to register receiver

```
val responseReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {

                Log.d("MyLog", "this log is not printed")
            }
}
NotificationCenter.addObserver(
    context, NotificationName.WebViewCookiesDidChange,
    responseReceiver
)
```

And after that somewhere I do

```
NotificationCenter.postNotification(
    context,
    NotificationName.WebViewCookiesDidChange,
    hashMapOf(
        NotificationKey.WebViewCookiesKey.name to cookies
    )
)
```

But `onReceive` is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class in which the BroadcastReceiver object is created must be initialized in onCreate().

For example this object is created in `class WebAuth(context: Context?) {}`

Wrong:

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    private var webAuth: WebAuth = WebAuth(context)

    // ...
}
```

Correct use:

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var webAuth: WebAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        webAuth = WebAuth(context)
    }

    // ...
}
```